# rebinding the select options via jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Below is how i made my select option list

```
<select  id="roomtype" name="roomtype" class="form-control select-block">
                    <?php 
                    // Populate dropdown list of room types
                    $room = new Rooms;
                    $room_types = $room->Bind_Room_Types();
                    foreach ($room_types as $key => $value)
                    {

                        echo '<option id="roomtypeoption" value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    unset($room);    
                    ?>
                    </select>
```

Now on an update request i made an ajax call which in return gives me a json data like below

```
[{"id":"1","roomno":"102","floor":"2nd","beds":"2 beds","roomtypeid":"1"}]
```

After getting the response i populated all the values on my form fields like below

```
       success: function(response) {
                // Taking ajax response into javascript objects to fill the form fields
                console.log(response);
                var object = {};
                object = $.parseJSON(response);
                $("#roomid").attr('value', object[0].id);
                $("#roomnumber").attr('value', object[0].roomno);
                $("#roomfloor").attr('value', object[0].floor);
                $("#roombeds").attr('value', object[0].beds);
                $("#roomtypeoption").remove(); // not working
                $("#roomtypeoption").attr('value', object[0].roomtypeid); //not work.
                $("#submit").attr('id', 'update').off('click');
            }
```

now in case of text fields its working fine , but when i came to select tag it is not getting updated.

2nd problem is that as you can see in my json i have pasted above. there is 'roomtypeid:1'. This is actually a foreign key. What i want is when my select list get updated on success of ajax then 'roomtypeid' should be placed in How to display the value against foreign key (roomtypeid)

I'm lost in this :(

Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach. Closing the question.

Comment: Don't do that, answer your own question and accept it. That is much more useful for anyone coming around later who may be doing the same thing.